# Convert coordinates (latitude, longitude) to GEOS hex format

Tags: python, django, geos

I have a Django website which uses GEOS for storing some points on map. In a table in DB I have 3 fields: longitude, latitude and something which I believe is hex format of [GEOS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/) position.

I need to import over 100 places from a file. I have latitudes and longitudes for all places. How can I convert them to GEOS format so I can insert the values to DB? Is there a way to do it without installing Python and Django? I don't have them as I'm not the developer of this application and I hope there maybe is some converter (I looked on the web but didn't find any) or other quick way.

Comment: Hi. It would be great if you post some examples of the triples lat, lon and hex.

Comment: Hello, sorry, as this question is 4 years old I no longer have this data to show :(. But you're right, I should have posted some examples back then.